# Trouble with rank and or dense rank

Tags: sql, postgresql, dense-rank

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
| customer_id | row_num_booking | row_num_service | row_num_perservice | dense_rank |       created_at        | service_type |   id    |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
|     1244180 |               1 |               4 |                  1 |          1 | 2020-11-23T13:28:02.163 | moving       | 2778630 |
|     1244180 |               2 |               3 |                  1 |          1 | 2020-11-24T10:48:51.994 | appclean     | 2781335 |
|     1244180 |               3 |               1 |                  1 |          1 | 2020-11-24T14:50:17.648 | homeclean    | 2782760 |
|     1244180 |               4 |               1 |                  2 |          2 | 2020-12-07T14:15:33.849 | homeclean    | 2822332 |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

but I expexted to be like this:

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
| customer_id | row_num_booking | row_num_service | row_num_perservice | dense_rank |       created_at        | service_type |   id    |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
|     1244180 |               1 |               4 |                  1 |          1 | 2020-11-23T13:28:02.163 | mv           | 2778630 |
|     1244180 |               2 |               3 |                  1 |          2 | 2020-11-24T10:48:51.994 | ac           | 2781335 |
|     1244180 |               3 |               1 |                  1 |          3 | 2020-11-24T14:50:17.648 | hc           | 2782760 |
|     1244180 |               4 |               1 |                  2 |          3 | 2020-12-07T14:15:33.849 | hc           | 2822332 |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+
```

Do you know how should i change in my code?

```
row_number() OVER (partition by b.customer_id,b.service_type order by b.service_type) dense_rank
```

Comment: Having the `service_type` in the partition will reset the rank/dense_rank to 1 for every new `service_type` that is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `b.service_type` from your `partition by` clause.